# Update Contact Attributes

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder

Can anyone shed some light on how Contact Attributes get updated?

We have our Marketing Cloud connect to Health Cloud with Marketing Cloud Connector. We also have a Journey that is running on a Data Extension. This Data Extension is populated with an hourly Automation that runs to pull the Lead data needed from the Synchronized Data Extension created by Marking Cloud Connector. This is all working as expected.

The issue is that the Journey is set to only accept Contacts where a Status field has a specific value. However, when I look at the Contacts from via Contact Builder, all the Contact attributes are blank. This doesn't make sense to me because when I view the Synchronized Data Extension and the Data Extension used as the Journey Source populated by the Automation, all data is there.

Tl;dr - how do I get data from a Synchronized Data Extension into the Contact attribute?

Comment: Have you done this step?   "Add Fields into Your Synchronized Data Sources from the Original Source" from https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_implement_synchronized_data_sources_best_practices.htm&type=5

Comment: @PeterNoges Yes, all the configuration has been done. The the relevant fields are showing as an attribute in the Contact Builder, but for some reason they are not getting updated data even though I can see the correct data in the Synchronized Data Extension.